# How can I calculate the position of a photographer and the focal length of the lens?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, rotations

Let's say I have an image of some mountains and a map where the mountains are marked. I ask myself is it possible to calculate the coordinates $x,y,z$ of the camera, the angles $\phi, \theta, \psi$ and the focal length of the lens $f$?

I have seen a attempt where some people were using rotation matrices
\begin{align*}
D_\phi = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & -\sin \phi & 0\\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \qquad D_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos \theta & - \sin \theta\\
0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} \qquad D_\psi = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \psi & 0 & - \sin \psi\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\sin \psi & 0 & \cos \psi
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

More over we have points in the image $(u_k, v_k)$ and the coordinates on the map as $(x_k, y_k, z_k)$. My idea was to find the minimum $e = v_A \times v_B $ where $v_A = (x', y', z') - (x_k, y_k, z_k) $ with $(x', y', z') $ as the focal point. From there I have the idea to make an iteration to find the minimum $e$. But how?

Are there any sources on that kind of problem? Sadly in my researches I haven't found anything related to this.